# can't fetch the data using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, mechanize

I was trying to write simple script with Beautiful Soup which can scrap just two information and generate a SQL file please from a website.

```
import mechanize
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

op = mechanize.Browser()
op.open("https://www.mentalhelp.net/symptoms/")
for link in op.links():
print link.text
print urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
get = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.mentalhelp.net/symptoms/").read()).findAll('p')
print get
print "\n"
```

error:

> C:\Python27>python symtoms.py   File "symtoms.py", line 8
>       print link.text
>           ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

I just want a script which will scrap those items and short descriptions and generate a SQL file which will have only two field "name" & "sug". "name" is those items and "sug" is those descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is important in Python , it is used to determine blocks , like for loop or if block or while loop or functions etc.

In the code you gave , the statement after the for loop is not correctly indented inside the for loop , and the for loop expects atleast one statement in its body , and I think you expected the lines below the for loop to be inside the for loop , so you should indent them inside the for loop .

Code -

```
for link in op.links():
    print link.text
    print urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
    get = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.mentalhelp.net/symptoms/").read()).findAll('p')
    print get
    print "\n"
```

Though I am not sure if that would get what you want , it would fix your current error .

---

For the new requirement to get just the `classic symptoms` and its descrciption , you can use -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.mentalhelp.net/symptoms/").read())
for div in soup.findAll('div',{'id':'page'}):
    for entrydiv in div.findAll('div',{'class':'h4 entry-title'}):
        print(entrydiv.get_text())
        print(entrydiv.next_sibling.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks man ! the code is working now at least. Yes it is not working for my purpose. I just need to get the symptoms name and the description under the symptoms lists. But it is showing lot. I am noob in python. can't make it yet. can you help please ?

Comment: I would be glad to try to help you.

Comment: glad that you are trying for me.

Comment: i just need the symptoms names and their description. descriptions can be full or partial, no problem. I just want to see how it works actually.

Comment: I just need the name "classic symptoms" & that description under <p> tag

<div class="h4 entry-title">
<a href="https://www.mentalhelp.net/articles/classic-symptoms-of-major-depression/">Classic Symptoms</a>
</div>

<p>
The classic symptoms of Major Depression are described in the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM-IV-TR), the widely accepted standard guidelines for psychiatric diagnosis. Symptoms associated with Major ...
</p>